# Do we have any Rest API or JQL query to fetch all issues in Jira Server having issuelinks?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql, jira-agile, jira-filter

Do we have any rest API or JQL query to execute which would fetch all the issues in a project having 0 or more issue links?

In Jira Cloud using "numberOfLinks" parameter we could fetch all the issues having issue links. But how do we fetch all the issues consisting of issue links in Jira Server/Datacenter?

Thanks & Regards,
Preethi H R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JQL query:

```
issuefunction in hasLinks() and project = XXX
```

That's show you all the issue in XXX project that has 1 link or more.
XXX = your project key

If you want to see all issues that doesn't have any links you can use:

```
issuefunction not in hasLinks() and project = XXX
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the required JQL filter.